# Jquery scroll помогите разобраться

Tags: jquery, html, прокрутка, css

Здравствуйте, читал кучу мануалов везде скролл к объекту, а мне бы просто скролл дива по оси_у скажем на 190px вниз\вверх, как реализовать?

Если несложно посмотрите пример: http://jsfiddle.net/JBAjc/4/

И несколько субвопросов:

- у поля content сделать бы overflow: auto; (вдруг скриптов нет), а далее скриптами включать overflow: hidden;
- скролилось бы ещё колёсиком, с тем же шагом (190px)

Спасибо за внимание, уверен этот пример ещё кому нибудь сгодится как справка.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как бы на форуме не принято выполнять работу за кого-то, но т.к. тут ничего особо сложного и нет, то [набросал вам примерчик](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/JBAjc/5/), а оптимизацию оставлю вам.

```js
var scrollBlock = $('.content'),
    dir = 0,
    cPos = 0,
    content = document.getElementById('content');
if (content.addEventListener) {
 content.addEventListener("mousewheel", getDelta, false);
 content.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", getDelta, false);
} else {
    content.attachEvent("onmousewheel", getDelta);
}

function getDelta(e) {
 var e = window.event || e;
 var delta = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, (e.wheelDelta || -e.detail)));
    startScroll(delta);
 return false;
}

function startScroll(obj){
    cPos = scrollBlock.scrollTop();
    if(obj.type == 'click'){
        obj.originalEvent.preventDefault();
        dir = ($(this).index('.bar') ? cPos + 130 : cPos - 130);
    } else {
        dir = (obj < 0 ? cPos + 130 : cPos - 130);
    }
    scrollBlock.animate({
        scrollTop: dir
    });
}
$('.bar').on('click',startScroll);
```

```css
* {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    border: none;
}

body {
    margin: 10px;
}
img {
    display: block;
    border: none;
    padding: 5px;
}

.bar {
    width: 190px;
    height: 30px;
    background: #ccc;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.bar:hover {
    background: #aaa;
}

.content {
    width: 190px;
    height: 390px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bar">НАВЕРХ</div>
<div class="content" id="content">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/180/120/sports/1" alt="peview"/>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/180/120/sports/2" alt="peview"/>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/180/120/sports/3" alt="peview"/>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/180/120/sports/4" alt="peview"/>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/180/120/sports/5" alt="peview"/>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/180/120/sports/6" alt="peview"/>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/180/120/sports/7" alt="peview"/>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/180/120/sports/8" alt="peview"/>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/180/120/sports/9" alt="peview"/>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/180/120/sports/10" alt="peview"/>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/180/120/sports/11" alt="peview"/>
</div>
<div class="bar">ВНИЗ</div>
```

Comment: Код лучше добавлять в ответ, вдруг сторонний сайт закроют?

Answer (score 0):

Вот так можно:

```
<div style="overflow-y: scroll; height: 190px;">
   ... ... ...
</div>
```